# Resque: Jobs must be placed onto a queue. No queue could be inferred for class Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, resque

I'm working on a rails app which involves using Resque. I have my queue defined in the worker class.

```
def self.queue
  @queue = :my_worker_queue
end
```

However I'm still getting

> Jobs must be placed onto a queue. No queue could be inferred for class Worker

Any ideas about how a queue should be defined? Thanks!

Comment: How did you run the app? you need to start the worker 
**$ QUEUE= my_worker_queue rake resque:work**

Comment: I start it by starting the rails server and posting to a table, which is supposed to enqueue a worker with Resque.enqueue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resque requires you to set the class-level instance variable with the queue name.  That's what your `self.queue` method does, but it'll only do it if you actually call it.

The easier option is to remove the `self.queue` method and put `@queue = :my_worker_queue` at the top of the class itself.

So it would be something like

```
class Worker
  @queue = :my_worker_queue

  def self.perform
    # do your stuff
  end
end
```

More information:
http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/performance/background_jobs.html